# How to upload file to Google Drive using duck?

Tags: macos, command-line, automation, google-apps

I usually access my Google Drive using [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/). So far, no problem with creating folders, moving files, etc. Then I noticed it has a command line interface called [duck](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/duck). Should be handy since I work in CLI a lot.

My question is how to upload a file with it?
Example: there's a folder called **dev123** under the root folder, and I want to upload a **test_30Oct2023.txt** on it. I tried:

```
duck --username <google username> --upload googledrive://dev123/test_30Oct2023.txt
```

Got this error:

> Missing argument for option: upload
>
> Try 'duck --help' for more options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cyberduck command-line documentation](https://docs.duck.sh/cli/#uploads-with-upload) documents the syntax.

> Upload file  to remote directory  using
>
> ```
> duck --upload protocol:/<folder>/ <file>
> ```

Comment: Ah silly me. I forget there should be a space before filename. Thanks.

Comment: Duck debugging to the rescue! Thanks for asking this question, I learned there's a CLI for this useful tool, @anta40